# How do I get EXCEL to interpret character variable without scientific notation in R using fwrite?

Tags: r, excel, csv, data.table

I have a relatively simple issue when writing out in R with `fwrite` from the `data.table` package I am getting a character vector interpreted as scientific notation by Excel. You can run the following code to create the data issue:

```
#create example
samp = data.table(id = c("7E39", "7G32","5D99999"))
fwrite(samp,"test.csv",row.names = F)
```

When you read this back into R you get values back no problem if you have scinote disable. My less code capable colleagues work with the csv directly in excel and they see this:

[image: What the excel user sees]

They can attempt to change the variable to text but excel then interprets all the zeros. I want them to see the original "7E39" from the data table created. Any ideas how to avoid this issue?

**PS: I'm working with millions of rows so `write.csv` is not really an option**

**EDIT**:

One workaround I've found is to just create a mock variable with quotes:

```
samp = data.table(id = c("7E39", "7G32","5D99999"))[,id2:=shQuote(id)]
```

I prefer a tidyr solution (pun intended), as I hate unnecessary columns

**EDIT2:**

Following R2Evan's solution I adapted it to data table with the following (factoring another numerical column, to see if any changes occured):

```
#create example
samp = data.table(id = c("7E39", "7G32","5D99999"))[,second_var:=c(1,2,3)]

fwrite(samp[,id:=sprintf("=%s", shQuote(id))],
          "foo.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this when writing to a CSV. I would just export to an xlsx separately with e.g. `openxlsx`, which lets you specify excel cell types. CSVs don't have types, so excel has to guess.

Comment: Bummer, I was afraid of that, well I found a temp work around, adding quotes to the variable to force excel to interpret it as quotes, I've added to my edit in case anyone finds it useful, hopefully someone comes along with some crazy solution

Answer (score 2):

It's a kludge, and dang-it for Excel to force this (I've dealt with it before).

```
write.csv(data.frame(id=sprintf("=%s", shQuote(c("7E39", "7G32","5D99999")))),
          "foo.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

This is forcing Excel to consider that column a formula, and interpret it as such. You'll see that in Excel, it is a literal formula that assigns a static string.

[image: screenshot of excel with formula]

This is obviously **not portable** and prone to all sorts of problems, but that is Excel's way in this regard.

(BTW: I used `write.csv` here, but frankly it doesn't matter which function you use, as long as it passes the string through.)

Comment: I adapted your solution and added it as an edit, this seems to work, I'm just worried about the non portable issue if it will trip up somewhere else in the future. Appreciate the help

Comment: Wait a sec ... you said this data has *"millions of rows"*, but Excel does not support over 1Mi. Which is it?

Comment: LOL, well the data in its raw format has millions of rows, the final product is just shy of a million, I wanted to make sure people didn't focus on write.csv

Answer (score 1):

Another option, but one that your consumers will need to do, not you.

If you export the file "as is", meaning the cell content is just `"7E39"`, then an auto-import within Excel will always try to be smart about that cell's content. However, you can manually import the data.

Using Excel 2016 (32bit, on win10_64bit, if it matters):

1. Open Excel (first), have an (optionally empty) worksheet already open
2. On the ribbon: *Data > Get External Data > From Text*
3. Navigate to the appropriate file (CSV)
4. Select "Delimited" (file type), click <kbd>Next</kbd>, select "Comma" (and optionally deselect any others that may default to selected), <kbd>Next</kbd>
5. Click on the specific column(s) and set the "Default data format" to "Text" (this will need to be done for any/all columns where this is a problem). Multiple columns can be <kbd>Shift</kbd>-selected (for a range of columns), but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-selected. <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
6. Choose the top-left cell to import/paste the data (or a new worksheet)
7. Select <kbd>Properties...</kbd>, and *deselect* "Save query definition". Without this step, the data is considered a *query* into an external data source, which may not be a problem but makes some things a little annoying. (For example, try to highlight all data and delete it ... Excel really wants to make sure you know what you're doing there.)

This method provides a **portable** solution. It "punishes" the Excel users, but anybody/anything else will still be able to consume the files directly without change. The biggest disadvantage with this method is that you won't know if somebody loads it incorrectly unless/until they get odd results when the try to use the data and some fields are silently converted.